# Using Strongly Typed models in Umbraco 7.6.9?

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I have tried looking into using Strongly Typed models (setting `Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode` to either `AppData` or `Dll`) for a while now, and I never fully understood how it works.

I already changed the `Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode` value and I generated the models inside the backoffice ModelsBuilder, then I included the `App_Data\Models` into Visual Studio, but what then?

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage<ContentModels.Home>
@using Our.Umbraco.Vorto.Models;
@using Our.Umbraco.Vorto.Extensions;
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
```

This is the code for my Home view. No matter what I try, I cannot access the `@Model.PROPERTY` or `@CurrentPage.PROPERTY` from my content. I can see the different properties inside my `MODEL.generated.cs` files.

What steps do I need to take, in order to do things like `@Model.PROPERTY`?

Answer (score 1):

You're not talking about "Dynamic" models, but Strongly Typed Models generated by **Models Builder**. By default Umbraco ships with PureLive setting which is keeping models in memory and generates them on the fly. It can be considered as "dynamic".

The tool and it's behaviour is well documented here: https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/Zbu.ModelsBuilder/wiki

Regarding modes of it, you can find all about it exactly in this place: https://github.com/zpqrtbnk/Zbu.ModelsBuilder/wiki/Builder-Modes

But answering your question - after you've changed the configuration, you need to compile your application as you need to keep those classes inside the DLL with which you're shipping your website. You're also able to regenerate models straight from your Developer's dashboard in Umbraco Backoffice.

**You need to remember that if you would like to use DLL, LiveDLL or PureLive configuration - you need to get rid of classes generated inside your AppData or any other directory used with this mode as you'll experience errors saying about 'More that one type want to be a model for content type File'.**

After that you should be able to access all properties of the document type via ***Model.Content.PropertyAlias***. You probably missed the **Content** object, which is the strongly typed, IPublishedContent representation of you document.

Hope it will help you to make it work :)

Comment: So I change it to `Dll` and I go to the backoffice to build the models, then they should work in VS? I haven't been able to get anything to work, unfortunately. The `App_Data\Models` should not be included in the project, right?

Comment: @MortenMoulder they should if you want to use them. If you'll change it to DLL you need to reference the generated DLL in your project and it should work too.

Comment: And the generated DLL is `Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.dll` inside the `\bin` folder, right?

Comment: Nope, says `More that one type want to be a model for content type File`.

Comment: Check my comment for your second post. I will update my reply.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so it seems like there has been some changes in the newest 7.6.9 release (or maybe 7.6.8). This is what I had to do now:

```
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.Enable" value="true" />
<add key="Umbraco.ModelsBuilder.ModelsMode" value="Dll" />
```

Then I can go into the backoffice and generate the models. The models **are** included into the project (location: `~\App_Data\Models\`). `Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels.dll` from the `~\bin\` folder has to be included as well.

Then, because of .NET Core I think, I got an error when I tried loading my application saying this:

> More than one type want to be a modle for content type File

This was caused because I had included **everything** inside `~\bin\`, which means I had also included my `Project.dll`, `Project.dll.config`, and `Project.pdb` files. The `Project.dll` file also includes the same models, apparently, so I had to exclude those 3 files.

Now it simply works and I can now do `@Model.Content.PROPERTY` flawlessly.

Comment: If you have modelsmode set up to DLL you can delete models from App_Data/Models as they are not used at all and that's why it was complaining for more than one model for type.

Comment: @MarcinZajkowski Nope it was complaining because of the `Project.dll` file.

Comment: Yes, becouse you had your models classes in the App_Data and it was compiled into this DLL as I presume? Hope you solved the issue finally?